# char unexpected behaviour with templated methods

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, implicit-conversion, stdtuple

I am working on a problem that should (since its HW) be solved by variadic templates. My lack of understanding prevents me from solving following error.

The code is:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename ... TL>
class LazySplitResult
{
public:
    LazySplitResult(TL ...pl) :storedParams(pl ...) {       }

    void doStuff()
    {
        // invoke method with inside parameters
        useStoredTuple(storedParams, std::index_sequence_for<TL...>());
    }
    template<typename T, typename T1, typename... Targs>
    void doInsideLogic(T&& value1, Targs&&  ... Fargs)
    {
        // there is some logic
        // for example this
        std::stringstream convert("0");
        // it works for string,double,int ... other types are not supported
        // so exception would be in place
        convert >> value1;
    }

    void doInsideLogic()
    {
    }       

private:
    template<std::size_t... Is>
    void useStoredTuple(const std::tuple<TL ...>& tuple,std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        wrapInsideLogic(std::get<Is>(tuple) ...);
    }

    void  wrapInsideLogic(TL && ... args)
    {
        doInsideLogic(args...);
    }

    std::tuple<TL ...> storedParams;
};

template<typename ...TL>
LazySplitResult<TL ...> getResult(TL && ...pl)
{
    return LazySplitResult<TL...>(pl  ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    int y;
    double z;

    // prepares an object
    auto lazyResult=getResult(x, '.', '-', y, 'x', z , 'a');

    // let it do its thing and set unset variables
    lazyResult.doStuff();

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << ", z = " << z << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is here

```
error C2664: 'void LazySplitResult<std::string &,char,char,int &,char,double &,char>::wrapInsideLogic(std::string &,char &&,char &&,int &,char &&,double &,char &&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char' to 'char &&'
source_file.cpp(40): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
source_file.cpp(18): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void LazySplitResult<std::string &,char,char,int &,char,double &,char>::useStoredTuple<0,1,2,3,4,5,6>(const std::tuple<std::string &,char,char,int &,char,double &,char> &,std::integer_sequence<_Ty,0,1,2,3,4,5,6>)'
```

It is copied from [rextester here](http://rextester.com/ELX41714).

The main part of the HW is to parse a formula and save the result in the variables like this:

```
// declare variables and initialize class with formula

parse(x, '.', '-', y, 'x', z , 'a');   
std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << ", z = " << z << std::endl;
```

The code does the same, except it does it in a lazy fashion so the parameters needs to be stored in a tuple for later use.

I tried to implement the same logic, except the laziness, without employing tuples and class with a success. It can be observed [here](http://rextester.com/ZTZJ95371). No error describind conversion errors was raised.

Can you please help me? I am completely lost. The entry method invocation is the same, the variadic template method that process the parameters have the same arguments... Only difference seems to be the tuple and class inbetween.

Comment: You haven't provided us the relevant code: Presumably, `x`, `y`, or `z` is const-qualified (or another qualifier), and therefore cannot be called without losing qualifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a useless template parameter `T1` in your `doInsideLogic` function template. Remove it.

The parameter of `wrapInsideLogic` is not a forwarding reference since `TL` is known and is not deduced. Its argument `std::get<Is>(tuple)` is of type `const TL&` since `tuple` is of type `const std::tuple<TL...>&`, thus does not match the parameter type `TL&&`. To fix this, there are two choices:

1. Use forwarding reference, i.e.

   ```
   template <typename... Targs>
   void wrapInsideLogic(Targs&&... args)
   {
       doInsideLogic(std::forward<Targs>(args)...);
   }
   ```
2. Use reference to const, i.e.

   ```
   void wrapInsideLogic(const TL&... args)
   {
       doInsideLogic(args...);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure... do you ask help for the code referred by first link or for the code referred by the second link?

I suppose is the second code so I suggest to reorder the definition of functions as follows.

First the ground case of recursion

```
void myFunc ()
 { std::cout << "end" << std::endl; }
```

Second, the recursive version of `myFunc()`

```
template <typename T, typename ... Targs>
void myFunc (T && value1, Targs && ... Fargs)
 {
   // there should be additional logic 
   // if value1 is char then skip it. But it was intentionally ommited
   std::cout << " do" << std::endl;

   const char* parsedValue = "0";
   std::stringstream convert(parsedValue);
   // cast current value according to thing.
   convert >> value1;

   myFunc(Fargs ...);
 }
```

Third, `test()`

```
template <typename ... Targs>
void test (Targs && ... args)
 { myFunc(args...); }
```

Now your code should compile.

If you write first `test()`, then the recursive `myFunc()` and last the ground case `myFunc()` you have that (1) `test()` call `myFunc()` when is undeclared and (2) the recursive `myFunc()` call the ground case `myFunc()` when is undeclared.

Comment: The code in the second rextester link work exaclty as I want. The other one in first link does not. The task is make it work and produce the same result.